# How to ensure all events have been fired before moving forwarded

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

How do I ensure that all the ontouch, onclick, etc listeners have been fired in the UI thread before moving forward with the test code? In other words, I have a spinner on which I have registered both onTouchListener and OnItemSelectedListener. I want to ensure that both these functions are called by my activity before I move on with testing. Is there any way this can be achieved in RoboElectric?